# JavaLite ActiveWeb rootPackage

Tags: activeweb

I'm developing a web application with ActiveWeb. I wanted to change the package from app.controller to be.coudron.graphplanner.controller

I created a file activewebproperties and placed it in src/main/resources

the contents of the file are:

```
freeMarkerConfig=be.coudron.graphplanner.config.FreeMarkerConfig

bootstrap=be.coudron.graphplanner.config.AppBootstrap

dbconfig=be.coudron.graphplanner.config.DbConfig

route_config=be.coudron.graphplanner.config.RouteConfig

controllerConfig=be.coudron.graphplanner.config.AppControllerConfig

rootPackage=be.coudron.graphplanner
```

When I start the app with mvn jetty:run

I get the error:

```
org.javalite.activeweb.ControllerException: controller must be 

in the 'app.controllers' package
```

What am i doing wrong?

There are no typos in the code nor the package names.

Answer (score 0):

the exception message is self-explanatory: "controller must be in the 'app.controllers' package"

The file `activeweb.properties` is part of the framework and not editable. With time, you will appreciate simplicity and consistency of the framework. It requires that controllers are placed into `app.controllers` package. Please, refer to http://javalite.io/structure_of_activeweb_project#location-of-controllers

Comment: Hi, Igor.So it is not possible to change the package name in an active web project? You havo to use app.controller another structure is not possible?

Thank you for the answer. Great product. Thank you.

Comment: @MattiasCoudron, correct, it is not possible and it is done like this on purpose. The link I provided has explanation of that. Thanks!